# Why can't DataTable.Load(IDataReader) load one row?

Tags: c#, datatable, idatareader

I am using `DataTable.Load(IDataReader)` to load data from db.
When I load one record, `DataTable.Rows.Count` shows a count of `0`, but when I load more than record `DataTable.Rows.Count` shows the right Count.

Does this mean `DataTable.Load Method` takes two rows and above?
This article was helpful but didn't answer my question
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load(v=vs.110).aspx.

Code

```
DataTable dt= new Datable
IDataReader rsg = DataClass.GetDBResults("sp_GetNames", "@Names", names);
 if (rsg.Read())
        {   
           dt.Load(rsg);
           int num = dt.Rows.Count;
                //More Code
        }
```

`num` is `0` if the procedure,`sp_GetNames` returns one record.

Comment: Please show your code. Without seeing what you're doing, it's not really possible to help you.

Comment: It the `.Rows.Count` is zero: you didn't load any rows; can you show your code?

Comment: It sounds to me like you've already read one record before you called Load(). The default position of an IDataReader is before the first record. Did you, perhaps, call Read() on the IDataReader, or something else that would have moved the reader's position, before you called Load()? As others have mentioned, seeing code would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Read()`, which reads the first record, and then you're calling `Load()`. The problem is that, after calling `Read()`, the pointer to the "current record" in `rsg` has already moved past the first record and is pointing to the next record (if there is one). The call to `Load()` is only going to read the rest of the records, since `IDataReader` is a forward-only mechanism.

Call `Load()` without the first call to `Read()`.

Comment: Thanks @JeffFerguson. That is the answer. You have saved me a lot.

Comment: @Angwenyi If you can cast to a [`DbDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `IDataReader` you could still do your if check via [`rsg.HasRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Scott I was wondering how I will check if the rsg has rows very helpful.